# how to use only certain addresses in subnet for traceroute?

Tags: pipe, ping, nmap, traceroute

First I try running `nmap -sn ip/24` to check live hosts on a subnet. It returns that all 255 hosts are live which I know is not true. I do `fping -g ip/24` and get that 7 hosts are up which makes more sense.

Now I'm trying to figure out network topology using `nmap -sn --traceroute ip/24` and the entire range of 0-255 is included. How can I just use the hosts that were returned by the fping command? I figure there has to be some way to pipe that argument or something to the nmap traceroute command, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Hmm, can you use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see how the `nmap` and `fping` packets outgoing differ?

Comment: so it looks like all the ones that `nmap -sn` shows are up but I don't think actually are, respond with ICMP echo request. I have very limited network knowledge so not sure how this works.

Comment: The `nmap -sn` is ping scan, but not necessary ICMP, if used in local network it will use ARP, in that case it may possible that a gateway could give fake arp responses. You can try `nmap -sn -PE` (real ICMP)

Comment: Thank you that seems to work properly to ignore the fake arp responses, but is it possible that it could miss a couple hosts that are intentionally trying to remain hidden? I got a result of 7 hosts when I think there should be 9 (this is a CTF subnet).

Comment: Yes, if a host don't reply to ICMP. But for that you can add yet another host discovery technique, like `-PS` for tcp syn, `-PA` for tcp ack, `-PU` for UDP, or yet others.

Comment: You can add multiple host discovery techniques: `nmap -sn -PE -PA -PE -PU --traceroute ip/24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use fping output as nmap target list:

```
fping -aqg ip/24 | xargs nmap -sn --traceroute
```

---

If your problem is that some gateway in your network is giving fake ARP responses (generating false positives), you can use `-sn -PE` to fix that:

```
nmap -sn -PE --traceroute ip/24
```

That way, nmap will exclusively show a host (and make a traceroute) if the host reply the ICMP request (ping).

Comment: I'm trying to look at the topology graphically, is it possible to make this command work for zenmap?